# Get names of files within a folder and use them to move in files with those names from another folder?

Tags: bash, unix

I have two folders as follows:

```
folder1
file1.shp
file1.dbf
file2.shp
file2.dbf
file3.shp
file3.dbf


folder2
file1.prj
file2.prj
file4.prj
```

What I want to do is to identify the files in folder1 that have the same names of files in folder2, independently of extension, and transfer them to folder2. The output should be:

```
folder2
file1.prj
file2.prj
file4.prj
file1.shp
file1.dbf
file2.shp
file2.dbf
```

This is what I have got so far:

```
for i in folder2/*.*; do
  FILE=$(basename "$i")
  echo find folder1 -name ${FILE%.*}.* -exec mv -i {} folder2 \;
done
```

This is what I get out of this code, but the files aren't moved from folder1 to folder2.

```
find folder1 -name file1.* -exec mv -i {} folder2 ;
find folder1 -name file2.* -exec mv -i {} folder2 ;
find folder1 -name file3.* -exec mv -i {} folder2 ;
```

Sorry, I started learning this sort of programming yesterday, so any help is very much appreciated.

[EDIT]

The code works without echo in line 3. Thanks to those who commented below for pointing it out.

```
for i in folder2/*.*; do
  FILE=$(basename "$i")
  find folder1 -name ${FILE%.*}.* -exec mv -i {} folder2 \;
done
```

Comment: I think you need to escape the `*` (for instance using `\*` or quoting:  `"file1.*"` -  otherwise the shell will expand it and find no matches.

Comment: Did you add `echo` to test the command first and forgot to remove it?

Comment: did you remove `echo` ??? You need to launch `find` directly not to echo.

Comment: Turns out the code works without echo. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just tried it like this, it works for me...

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in folder2/*
do
filename=${f##*/}
filename_without_ext=${filename%.*}

for ff in ${filename_without_ext[@]}
do
    find folder1 -name ${ff}.* -exec mv -i {} folder2 \;
done

done
```